# What is the best approach to develop a modern web app that uses ads

Tags: javascript, web, mobile, single-page-application

I would like to build a mapping app that uses a freemium model, ie ads for free customers.

The initial app needs to be a web app, then the plan is to develop a mobile app.

I have found that SPAs do not work at all well with Google Ads, so is there a better approach for a Javascript web app?  Based on my findings that a. SPAs do not work nicely with Google Ads and b. that when set up optimally, due to the lack of page refreshes required, they yield significantly lower ad revenue.  Therefore I can only assume the best approach would be to build an old-school multi page web app (yuk).

Are there any new/recommended approaches for this.  And/or a platform for both web and mobile that would suit?